Introduction of function symbols
According to this link, in order to introduce a new function symbol one needs to prove the formula $\forall x_1,...,x_n\exists!y:P(y,x_1,...,x_n)$. This allows for the introduction of a new $n$-ary function symbol $f$ accompanied by the axiom $\forall x_1,...,x_n:P(f(x_1,...,x_n),x_1,...,x_n)$.
The most common example I have seen is the one of introducing the notation $f(x)=y$ for a function $f:X \to Y$ of some sets $X$ and $Y$. However, in order to even talk about functions, one needs to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are sets and that $f$ is a function between these two sets. Thus one is in the situation that $\forall X,Y,f,x \exists!y :P(y,X,Y,f,x)$ for the appropriate $P$. Thus one would only be allowed to introduce a $4$-ary function symbol that is distinct from $f$ to denote that $y$, so something like $A(X,Y,f,x)$.
$(1)$ This leads to the question, why it is allowed to introduce $f(x)$? Wouldn't it have to be something like the $A$ I introduced above, meaning a $4$-ary symbol and not a $1$-ary symbol?
My guess is that the technically the function symbols are always introduced in context where $X$ and $Y$ are already assumed to be sets, so for example when one wants to prove a statement of the form $\forall X,Y :P(X,Y),$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets. In the proof of such a statement one would assume that $X$ and $Y$ are sets (thus fixed). If one can then prove that there is a function $f:X \to Y$ then one knows that $\forall x \in X \exists !y \in Y: (x,y) \in f$. In this context one would be allowed to introduce a new $1$-ary function symbol $B$ alongside the axiom $\forall x \in X:(x,B(x)) \in f$.
$(2)$ So technically we cant use the symbol $f$ for $B$ here, right? In particular the symbol $f$ already is in use, so one can't use it for a new function symbol I suppose. I guess one is just being informal here?
$(3)$ The predicate $P$ includes the unbound variables $X,Y$ and $f$ here. Is this allowed for predicates in FOL? Or must every predicate only include bound variables?
$(4)$ If my guess is the answer to the question $(1)$, this would mean that the notation $f(x)=y$ for a function $f$ would not be introduced globally right? So whenever one deals with a function, one would have to introduce the function symbol again and again, right?

See this post for examples as well as Semantics and Logical structure in Definitions. And see Understanding extension by definition.

You have to be clear about: (i) adding a function symbol to the predicate logic language, in which case we have no sets etc, and (ii) proving using set theory that a function exists.
Example: we add to the "basic" language of set theory, that uses only $\in$ and $\emptyset$, the two new function symbols: $\cap$ and $\cup$ for the intersection and union operations.
And here is an example of non-set function: "the Father of...". Assuming that we have a binary relation $\text {Father}(y,x)$ saying that "y is Father of x", we prove that $∀x∃!y \text {Father}(y,x)$  and then we add the new function symbol that allows us to write $y = \text {FatherOf}(x)$.
